# Splitting circle for two areas by chord

Tags: geometry, circles

Is there any algorithms for splitting circle for two areas by chord in ratio $a:b$ (which natural), using only compasses and line?

Comment: If you want to do a 1:2 division you must solve $\frac\pi3=\theta-\sin\theta$, which isn't possible by C&S...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, thank you for comment! Impossible of this case not mean impossible of some others, right?

Comment: True. A 1:1 division is clearly doable with C&S.